# A question on Lebesgue Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show if $E_k \subset (0, 1)$, $(k=1,...,n)$, and $\sum_{1 \le k \le n}{\mu(E_k)} > n -1$, then $\mu(\bigcap_{1 \le k \le n}{E_k}) > 0$.

Intuitively this seems like such an obvious statement but I have been having a hard time showing this. Following is some analysis I was able to perform regarding this problem.

Using Demorgan's law we know  $\bigcap_{1 \le k \le n}{E_k} = (\bigcup_{1 \le k \le n}{{E_k}^\mathsf{c}})^\mathsf{c}$, and obviously measure of $\bigcup_{1 \le k \le n}{{E_k}^\mathsf{c}}$ being a subset of $(0,1)$ is bounded between 0 and 1. I am having a hard time trying to exploit the lower bound of the finite sum of measures. I thought of using inclusion-exclusion but that would probably create other terms as well.

How can I prove this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $F_k = (0,1) \backslash E_k$. What do you know about 
$\sum_k \mu(F_k)$?

Comment: I think i only know that $0 \le \sum_{k}{\mu(F_k)} \le n$, and similar upper bound also exists on $n-1 \le \sum_{k}{\mu(E_k)} \le n$. Am i missing something ?

Comment: actuallly i think i can prove a tighter bounds on $ 0 < \sum_{k}{\mu(F_k)} < 1$. Not sure how to use this info now though.

Comment: @Hardy, use Boole's inequality, $1>\sum_k\mu(F_k)\ge\mu\left(\bigcup_k F_k\right)$. What is $\mu\left(\bigcup_k F_k\right)$ equal to?